# How remove extra spaces in DialogueFragment?

Tags: android, android-view, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

How remove spaces in in left,right and above dialogue views to re-size this dialogue below ?

or in another way how make this dialogue only occupy red rectangle ?
thanks in advance .

[image]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat"
        android:hint="enter value"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:theme="@style/dialog_blue_button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            style="@style/dialog_blue_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:id="@+id/canel"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <Button
            style="@style/dialog_blue_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:text="ok"
            android:id="@+id/ok"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**DialogueFragment class**

```
public class InsertDialogue extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
Button ok, cancel;
EditText edit;
Insert communicator;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    communicator = (Insert) activity;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setCancelable(false);
    getDialog().setTitle("New input");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.insertdialogue, null);
    ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.ok);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.canel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.ok) {
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (!text.matches("") &&!text.matches("^\\.$") ) {

            float s = Float.parseFloat(edit.getText().toString());
            if (s > 0) {
                communicator.input(s);
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    } else {
        dismiss();
    }

}

interface Insert {
    public void input(float Value);
}
```

}

Comment: You've given padding and margin in layout. remove those then there won't be any spacing. use only where needed.

Comment: i removed padding from buttons and textview .still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add these lines below `getDialog().setTitle("New input");`

```
TextView titleTextView = (TextView) this.getDialog().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
titleTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

this will make the title of your dialog fragment accessible, and you can customize it.